# Why emulator is hesitating to show android application?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Unable to show android application on the running emulator.
Actually i am trying to consume a web service by the method SOAP from android,i guess i have done each code properly,but when i am trying to run this applicaion,the console and the logcat is saying like this

*Console*

```
[2012-09-11 16:26:47 - TMS_Chart] -----------
[2012-09-11 16:26:47 - TMS_Chart] Android Launch!
[2012-09-11 16:26:47 - TMS_Chart] adb is running normally.
[2012-09-11 16:26:47 - TMS_Chart] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-09-11 16:26:47 - TMS_Chart] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2012-09-11 16:26:47 - TMS_Chart] Performing sync
[2012-09-11 16:26:47 - TMS_Chart] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Android22-API-8'
[2012-09-11 16:26:47 - TMS_Chart] Uploading TMS_Chart.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-09-11 16:26:50 - TMS_Chart] Installing TMS_Chart.apk...
[2012-09-11 16:26:54 - TMS_Chart] Success!
[2012-09-11 16:26:54 - TMS_Chart] \TMS_Chart\bin\TMS_Chart.apk installed on device
[2012-09-11 16:26:54 - TMS_Chart] Done!
```

And the logcat is saying like this,

*Logcat*

```
09-11 16:26:53.463: D/AndroidRuntime(494): Shutting down VM
09-11 16:26:53.473: D/dalvikvm(494): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
09-11 16:26:53.513: I/AndroidRuntime(494): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
09-11 16:26:58.443: D/dalvikvm(191): GC_EXPLICIT freed 88 objects / 3824 bytes in 146ms
09-11 16:29:42.536: D/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
09-11 16:34:42.583: D/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
09-11 16:39:42.626: D/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

So here i cannot find my launched android application on the emulator.

can any one let me know about this issue?

thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: it says you dont have a launcher activity ie an activity with this  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you dont have a launcher activity. Add foloowing intents to the activty you want to be launced as a default activity:

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
</intent-filter>
```